# Почему используется *(p + i) вместо p[i] при взятии значения указателя?

Tags: c++

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    found = (trial % *(primes + i)) == 0;
    if (found == 0)
        break;
}
```

Только начал изучать C++. Не могу понять, почему в этой строке при вычислении остатка используется именно `*(primes + i)`, а не `primes[i]`.

Comment: Пальцы человек разминает (больше символов набирать).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы показать, что инкрементирование указателя на массив даст весьма конкретный результат.

Comment: @ХэшКод, спасибо. Вставил, что предлагала проверка орфографии, не посмотрев.=)

Comment: только чтобы показать это? или же здесь есть еще какой-то смысл, о котором я пока не догадываюсь?)

Comment: Надо смотреть контекст. В отрыве от него - все равно как бегать по массиву.

Answer (score 5):

> Не могу понять, почему в этой строке
> при вычислении остатка используется
> именно *(primes + i), а не primes[i].

Ну это как бы такая фишка: показать свое владение пойнтерной арифметикой.

Ну примерно как моряки говорят вместо кОмпас - компАс. Менты: дело не возбужденО, а возбУждено и проч.